# What type of language Kotlin is? Pure OOP's or Functional

Tags: kotlin

I'm learning `Kotlin`. Having Java background I know, Java is pure object oriented language. Everything has to be inside class even the main function.

That's why I'm wondering is `Kotlin` a true object oriented language?
Because it is possible to write functionl programs with Kotlin.

```
package functions

fun sayHello(name: String): String {
    val personName = name
    return "hello $personName"
}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(sayHello("Netra"))
}
```

Comment: I think you have answered your own question: it is neither. It is not purely OO, it is not purely functional.

Comment: Your example of a "functional" program could also be written in Java with static methods.

Comment: I would argue that Java isn't a "pure object oriented language" either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually most language analysts do not regard Java as a purely Object Oriented Language at all.  All code needing to be in a class is not a good test, and a better test is everything in the language an object.  In Java, many language elements, very notably methods and functions (functions were for a long time missing but then added recently through lambdas) were not available as objects.

Kotlin does correct many of the flaws of Java in being OO, although Java itself has also been slowly correcting these flaws.  But generally it could be said that Kotlin could be considered more 'OO' than Java, largely as a benefit of being a newer design able to correct errors of the past.

Being able to write functions, as is now possible in Java with Lambdas, is not 'anti object oriented', the real test is if the functions themselves can be first class objects.  By adding functions Java has not become less OO, and in fact Java is gradually becoming more OO over time.  Research 'Is Java OO?'

Being able to support functional programming does not make a language 'non-oo' either. Consider (or research) scala.

Functional programming may be as old or even older than OO, but has become more popular recently and this is reflecting in more FP features being in new languages, and Kotlin also provides more support FP.  No language is 'pure' FP and even a 'print' statement has side effects.

Kotlin provides support for both idioms, and may be more OO than Java but is considered less FP than more dedicated FP languages.  More FP features may be added over time.

----- addition of a reference
For a source on Java with respect to OO, I suggest [Dr Russel Winder](https://www.russel.org.uk/stories/cv.html) as an authority, among other credentials, co-author of [Developing Java Software](http://au.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP000931.html) which reached 3 editions.  For one reference, [see this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_Z_8HXt68k) with a slide at 1:40 with the statement

> Java is a 1990s imperative language that isn't really object-oriented.

As an acknowledged Java expert there is further explanation of this view both in that video and other presentations by Russel.  This view is also expressed by many other Java experts and I may add references, but it would make this post too long to add as much detail for each example.

Comment: If u could direct me to some specific reliable resources, that will be helpful

Comment: I added a specific reliable source in the original post as links word better there than in comments.